# password for Login Application in c# windows form

Tags: c#, textbox

How to display password as "********" in the text box instead of
displaying real password
on text box?
Is it possible in c#

Thanks

Comment: If you're going to downvote someone, at least have the basic decency to explain why...

Comment: Wasn't me, but my guess would be because you can literally paste the question, as is, into Google and immediately discover the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set up a property of `textbox`:

```
textBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
```

and you can also set the `char` for password what you want to:

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
```

Comment: [CHECK HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_properties.aspx) there is no such property for the textbox in c#

Comment: Where is `IsPassword`? Looks like that the OP uses `winforms`.

Comment: It is not the answer and someone upvoted it :)

Comment: yeah it is not the answer

Comment: `The UseSystemPasswordChar property has precedence over the PasswordChar property. Whenever the UseSystemPasswordChar is set to true, the default system password character is used and any character set by PasswordChar is ignored.` (from [TextBox.PasswordChar Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx)) - so just `textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';` should suffice.

Comment: when i used textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';           Error1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char'

Comment: @NewComer - are you sure you're setting it to `'*'`? From the message it sounds like you're trying to set it to `"*"` - subtile difference.

Comment: @NewComer use single quotations `''`. Double quotations `""` are for `strings`.

Comment: yeah it worked .. the mistake was '*'.. Thank you Corak and Shaharayar.. And thanks to everyone.. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also set the char for password what ever you want:

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties of password textbox and make Password char property to *

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Set the property TextBox.PasswordChar to whatever char you want to be displayed instead of the actual char
2. Set the property TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar to true. This will use and display the defaul password-char (a dot in Win 7) instead of the actual char.